# I need a formula that can identify 2 consecutive periods during a time off for drivers

Tags: microsoft-excel

New DOT hours of service rules require two consecutive periods of 1am to 5am during a DOT driver's time off.

If I input the log off time and date, and the log on time and date, what is the formula that will tell me if the two consecutive periods of 1am to 5am have been met?

Answer (score 1):

(If I understood your question correctly) If log off time is in A2 and log on time is in B2, this should work:

```
=IF((B2-INT(B2))*24*3600>18000;IF((INT(B2)-A2)*24*3600>82800;"TRUE";"FALSE");IF((INT(B2)-A2)*24*3600>169200;"TRUE";"FALSE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

dusan.bajic's solution works for me but I think you can do that more easily with this formula

`=B2>=INT(A2)+29/24+(MOD(A2,1)>1/24)`

that works because if the A2 time is before 1:00 the B5 time/date has to be at least 5:00 the following day....but if A2 time is later then it's 24 hours later.

Note: I'm assuming that you need to **full** consecutive periods (not some partial periods that would add up to 8 hours between those times)

Edit:....or even simpler version

`=B2>=CEILING(A2-1/24,1)+29/24`

Comment: +1, this really is more elegant